# Why does my XSLT 'key' call require for-each clause?

Tags: xslt

I've only been using XSLT a very short time, and I have a conceptual question.

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>AAA - BBB</root>
```

and an XSLT file

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:param name="DATA" select="999"/>

<lookup:strings>
    <string id='eee'>XXX</string>
    <string id='fff'>YYY</string>
</lookup:strings>

<xsl:key name='look' match='lookup:strings/string' use='@id' />

<xsl:variable name='strings' select='document("")//lookup:strings' />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>$strings=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$strings"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>(A)</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select='$strings'>
        <xsl:value-of select='key("look", "eee")'/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>(B)</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='key("look", "eee")'/>
    <xsl:text>(C)</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,' - ')"/>
    <xsl:text>(D)</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$DATA"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This produces the output:

```
$strings= XXX YYY 
(A)XXX(B)(C)AAA(D)999
```

The question:

Why does the key lookup require the for-each in (A) in order to produce output?  In (C), the select evaluates the function to a string, and in (D), the select evaluates a parameter to a string.  Why doesn't the function in (B) evaluate to XXX?

I know I'm missing an important concept here, but several hours of looking at various XSLT documentation hasn't returned an answer.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key()` function looks up the key table of the current document, which is the document of the current node.

The `<xsl:for-each>` instruction positions the current node to the node given in the XPath address, which in your case, is in the stylesheet because of the `document('')` call.

So you are using `<xsl:for-each>` to ensure that the current document is the stylesheet at the time of the call, so that the lookup table used is the lookup table for the stylesheet and not the lookup table for the data file.

In XSLT 2.0 there is a third argument to `key()` that is the node to use as the apex of a subtree (in an arbitrary tree) in which to search the lookup table.

There is helpful information on pages 319-323 of my XSLT book that is available for free download on a "try and buy" basis at http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/training/#ptux ... if you decide not to pay for the book, please delete the copy that you download for free.

Comment: Indeed, I thought that the `key` function in XSLT 1.0 only worked on the current input document, yet the OP's code works as described.  I've worked around this in the past by  breaking up transforms so that I could use `key` as needed.  Am I remembering something wrong?  Is there an exception when the `document()` is the transform itself?

Comment: Thank you.  Your explanation was clear, concise and exactly what I needed.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @harpo, the `key` function works on the current document, whether that be the input document, some other input document, or when using the stylesheet as the input document as with `document('')`.  There are no special cases.  When the relative URI `''` is resolved using the base URI of the stylesheet, the resulting URI is that of the stylesheet.  Thus calling `document('')` simply treats the stylesheet tree as an input tree.

Comment: Thanks, G.  I will definitely have to try that.  You're saying all I have to do to use `key` is set the context.  This incidentally means that the same `key` can create multiple indexes depending on how it is used.  Interesting.